# What is the alternative of pipe for graphics?

Tags: x11, gui

When you start an application which has a GUI, the GUI starts in a new window.

Is it possible to "redirect" this graphical output in another output? (for example a list of files, or a video stream)

In alternative, would it be possible to create a virtual window which emulates the actual screen, in order to capture the full graphical output of the embedded application?

Comment: Yes, you can do all that. What is it you want to solve? You could use a VNC server, a X11 to VNC bridge, a gstreamer screen capture (as in webcam recording), ... If you tell us what you are trying to do, we might be able to answer more specifically.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani thanks for the advices. I'd like to process the screen as a flow of matrices of pixels  (or a video) in a python or Java or C++ program. The screen must contain only the application window without being hidden by other windows currently opened